# Sample random variates from a Normal Inverse Gaussian (NIG) distribution

Tags: c++, math, boost, probability, distribution

How do I sample random variates from a Normal Inverse Gaussian (NIG) distribution?

I need to generate 100 numbers from the NIG distribution.

I use boost::math::inverse_gaussian but it does not have an operator() member function like std::normal_distribution

Edit: Hörmann, W., Leydold have been doing some research into this topic:

1. Paper Hörmann, W., Leydold, J. Generating generalized inverse Gaussian random variates. Stat Comput 24, 547–557 (2014). [https://doi.org/10.1007/s11222-013-9387-3[https://doi.org/10.1007/s11222-013-9387-3][3]](https://doi.org/10.1007/s11222-013-9387-3%5Bhttps://doi.org/10.1007/s11222-013-9387-3%5D%5B3%5D)
2. Slides [UNU.RAN](https://indico.cern.ch/event/13356/contributions/1359421/attachments/102145/145789/leydold_root07.pdf)
3. An Implementation in C [Universal Non-Uniform RANdom number generators](http://statistik.wu-wien.ac.at/unuran/)

Comment: see [here](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/math/doc/sf_and_dist/html/math_toolkit/dist/dist_ref/dists/inverse_gaussian_dist.html): "Non-member Accessors - All the usual non-member accessor functions that are generic to all distributions are supported: ...."

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number can you spell this out to me, please?
I would like to get 100 numbers from the nig distribution
[boost docs](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_76_0/libs/math/doc/html/math_toolkit/dist_ref/nmp.html) for the non-member functions.

Comment: Do I need a MC simulation to sample them?

Comment: Looks like https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_Gaussian_distribution has a section about sampling which gives a simple algorithm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't find the inverse Gaussian distribution in [Boost.Random](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_76_0/doc/html/boost_random/reference.html#boost_random.reference.distributions).

You can use the so-called [inverse transform sampling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_transform_sampling) technique. That is, you take the inverse *cdf* (i.e. the quantile function) of the inverse Gaussian distribution, and you apply it to a sample of uniformly random numbers in (0,1).

Something like that:

```
boost::math::inverse_gaussian my_ig(2, 3);
double inverseCDFig(double p){
  return boost::math::quantile(my_ig, p);
}
```

Then you use [std::uniform_real_distribution](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_real_distribution) to generate uniformly random numbers between 0 and 1, say `u[i]` for `i = 0; i < N`, and you compute `inverseCDFig(u[i])` for every `i`. In this way you get a random sample from the inverse Gaussian distribution.